# Custom Authorize Attribute and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, authorize-attribute

I am implementing Action/Activity based authorization in my asp.net application. I am trying to make this a reusable library so that I can use it for other projects. I am using Entity Framework for Data Access.

I was able to implement the functionality but not sure how to configure Entity Framework connection string for Authorize attribute.

Custom Authorize Attribute:

```
public class AuthorizeAction: AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private string _actions;
    private string[] _actionsSplit = new string[0];

    public string Actions
    {
        get { return _actions ?? String.Empty; }
        set
        {
            _actions = value;
            _actionsSplit = value.Split(',');
        }
    }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        string userid = string.Empty;

        if (httpContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");
        }

        IPrincipal user = httpContext.User;
        if(!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return false;
        }

        userid = user.Identity.Name;

        if(_actionsSplit.Length > 0)
        {
            AuthManager manager = new AuthManager();
            if (!manager.AuthorizeAction(_actionsSplit, userid)) //This will authorize the user against an action
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

AuthManager class that I am using has a overload method to accept Entity Framework Connection String name for configuration file but I am not sure how can this be configurable or user supplied.

AuthManager Code:

```
public class AuthManager
{
    private string connectionConfigName = "AuthorizationContext";

    public AuthManager() { }

    public AuthManager(string connectionName)
    {
        connectionConfigName = connectionName;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Authorizes the actions against userid supplied
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="actionNames">Comma seperated list of action names</param>
    /// <param name="userAlias">Unique user identifier</param>
    /// <returns>True if user has access to atleast one of the actions supplies otherwise false</returns>
    public bool AuthorizeAction(string[] actions, string userAlias)
    {
        using (AuthorizationContext context = new AuthorizationContext(connectionConfigName))
        {
            //List<string> actions = actionNames.Split(',').ToList<string>();

            var count = (from ur in context.UserRoles
                         join ra in context.RoleActions on new { Key1 = ur.RoleId, Key2 = ur.UserAlias } equals new { Key1 = ra.RoleId, Key2 = userAlias}
                         join a in context.Actions on ra.ActionId equals a.ActionId
                         where actions.Contains(a.ActionName) && ra.Allow == true
                         select ur).Count();

            return (count > 0);
        }
    }
}
```

I looked at using RoleProvider but as I am not going to use any of the built in functionality not sure if that is a good idea. Please help.

Comment: Isnt this all dependent on how AuthManager is implemented? Where is the code for that?

Comment: Added code for AuthManager.

Comment: The connectionstring should be in the config file.

Comment: You know, this would work a lot better to just implement claims, and apply specific claims to specific actions, then assign those claims to specific users.. no custom authorization needed.

Comment: We also had similar needs and we found custom role provider quite useful, override RoleProvider class and then do the stuff.Over ride the existing functionality.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch I don't have much idea on Claims. But Isn't my AuthManager code will be same even if I use claims? I want to store these actions and permission for those actions in the database so that users can configure them from the application. What is the advantage of using claims over above approach? Any reference are highly appreciated. Thanks.